# Android ListView Get Item ID

Tags: android, android-listview

In the below code I am making a string array and splitting the string to strip out the IDs. Instead of this I want associative array so that I can select ID of the item from array. Can anyone help !

```
String[] data={"12__Item 1","14__Item 2","34__Item 3","56__Item 4"};
lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.leaning_path_list_view);

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.learning_path_single_row,R.id.textView,data);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);


    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            String item =(String)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
            String[] parts = item.split("__");

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "ID: " + parts[0]+" Title: " + parts[1], Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();


        }
    });
```

Comment: your code is not starting a new activity, since startActivity(i); is commented out

Comment: Sorry I have updated the question

Comment: please edit your question to display clearly what is your problem.

Comment: Basically I want an array with IDs and Titles as ListView and when I click some item I should be able to get the ID of that title from th array.

Comment: Why don't you create a class that will have the id and the string as members. And use a custom adapter.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public class YourItem {

    private String title;
    private long id;

    public YourItem(long id, String title){     
        this.setTitle(title);
        this.setId(id);             
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return title;
    }
}
```

Call your adapter like this:

```
YourItem[] data={new YourItem(12,"Item 1"),
                 new YourItem(14,"Item 2")
                 new YourItem(34,"Item 3")
                 new YourItem(56,"Item 4")
                 };


ArrayAdapter<YourItem> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<YourItem>(this,R.layout.learning_path_single_row,R.id.textView,data);
```

And in your Listener do something like this:

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        String title= parent.getItemAtPosition(position).getTitle();
        long id = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).getId()

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "ID: " + id +" Title: " + title, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();


    }
});
```

I think it should do it.

Comment: If this helped you, you should accept the answer so everybody knows that your done with this question. Thanks